# Writing XML file Using DOM

Tags: php, xml, dom

I am trying to get data from database and write it to xml file using DOM.

```
$doc = new DomDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$doc->formatOutput = true;

$root = $doc->createElement('root');
$doc->appendChild($root);

$blocks = $doc->createElement('blocks');
$root->appendChild($blocks);

while($result_array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
    $cms_block = $doc->createElement('cms_block');

    foreach($result_array as $fieldname => $fieldvalue)
    {
        /*This is part that is not working*/

        $key = $doc->createElement($fieldname);
        $cms_block->appendChild($key);
        $value = $doc->createTextNode($fieldvalue);
        $key->appendChild($value);          
    }

    $stores = $doc->createElement('stores');
    $cms_block->appendChild($stores);

    $item = $doc->createElement('item');
    $stores->appendChild($item);

    $itemvalue = $doc->createTextNode('0');
    $item->appendChild($itemvalue); 

    $blocks->appendChild($cms_block);       
}
```

The above code works and mostly does what I need it to do but it fails within foreach loop and the elements and value that I am trying to add within foreach does not work.

Example of $result_array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)

```
Array ( [title] => Footer Links [identifier] => footer_links [is_active] => 1 )
```

Array ( [title] => Footer Links [identifier] => footer_links [is_active] => 1 )

It would really help me if someone can tell me what I am doing wrong within foreach loop which is not adding the data that I am getting from database to the xml file please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to add data from your $results_array

```
$cms_block->appendChild($doc->createElement($fieldname, $fieldvalue));
```

**UPDATE**
Move $blocks->appendChild($cms_block); to the end of your while loop .

Comment: Thank you for you reply I tried that and all it prints is 'footer_links 1 0' for the example I gave in my question.

Comment: I did change $key to fieldname and $value to $filedvalue at first try.

Comment: Move `$blocks->appendChild($cms_block);` to the end of your while loop and see if that fixes it. Also, can you provide the xml file that's generated by your code.

Comment: Moving $blocks->appendChild($cms_block); outside while loops work. thanks. However one of the field needs adding CDATA how can I achieve that please

Comment: Take a look at [createCDATASection](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createcdatasection.php)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89706/discussion-between-user4676307-and-ali-idrees).